# Why SQLite replace function produce an error in my Android App?

Tags: android, sqlite, replace

I need to custom order items in a list. To do this I add an extra column and ORDER by it:

```
public Cursor getAllItems(){
qry = "SELECT id,details,type, 
(replace(replace(replace(replace(Type,'Day','1Day'),'MONTHLY','2MONTHLY'),
'EBUDGET','4BUDGET'),'CARD','3CARD')) as list1" +
" from items_TB order by substr(list1,1,4), details";
c2 = db.rawQuery(qry, null);
return c2;
}
```

this works well, compiles and installs but also produces an error:

')', , SELECT, VALUES or WITH expected, got 'replace'.

note than 80 lines before this function I have a very similar query (different table) with no error warning:

```
public Cursor getRecordsMonth(String month,String q) {
    if(q.equals("partial")){
    qry="Select id, DATE, Amount, (replace(replace(replace(replace(Type,'Day-',''),'MONTHLY- 
    ',''),'EBUDGET',''),'CREDIT -',''))  || ' • ' || DETAILS,Type "+
    " from records_TB where date like '%"+month+"' order by Type desc";
    }
    c1 = db.rawQuery(qry, null);
    return c1;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's useful to log the  `qry` string after you constructed it and before you use it in the `rawQuery` as quite often it is easier to see the problem once the string has been constructed, usually a missing/extra space, comma, bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Android Studio is parsing the SQL incorrectly, because of the use of replace (change all replace's to replac and the syntax error is surpressed (obviously the SQL would then fail, if left at that)).

To circumvent what appears to be a bug you can "fool" Android Studio by using :-

```
public Cursor getAllItems(){

    //qry = "SELECT id,details,type, (replace(replace(replace(replace(Type,'Day','1Day'),'MONTHLY','2MONTHLY'),'EBUDGET','4BUDGET'),'CARD','3CARD')) as list1" + " from items_TB order by substr(list1,1,4), details";

    String list1Col = "(replace(replace(replace(replace(type,'Day','1Day'),'MONTHLY','2MONTHLY'), 'EBUDGET','4BUDGET'),'CARD','3CARD')) AS list1";
    qry = "SELECT id,details,type," + list1Col + " from items_TB order by substr(list1,1,4), details";
    return db.rawQuery(qry, null);
}
```

- Original has been commented out.
- you can return the result directly, so no need for `c2 = ....  return c2`

An alternative, that also avoids the syntax error would be to utilise the SQLiteDatabase `query` convenience method, which could be :-

```
/* Alternative using the query convenience method */
public Cursor getAllItemsAlt1() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            "id","details","type","(replace(replace(replace(replace(type,'Day','1Day'),'MONTHLY','2MONTHLY'),'EBUDGET','4BUDGET'),'CARD','3CARD')) AS list1"
    };
    return db.query("items_TB",columns,null,null,null,null,"substr(list1,1,4),details");
}
```

Comment: I use the first suggestion, very clever and clear answer. Thank you so much.